# Why do I get an Automation Error when copy-pasting shapes with an Excel macro, but not if I slow down the code?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, copy-paste

When I try to copy-paste some existing shapes into cells depending on the value of the cells, my macro will fail after few copies (less than 10) with the following error:

> Run-time error '-2147221040 (800401d0)': Automation error
>   OpenClipboard Failed

I initially thought that might be some kind of Clipboard buffer issue so I added this command after each paste:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But it didn't change anything.

But then I noticed that if put some breakpoint on my code and run it "step-by-step" (F5 when at the breakpoint), it works fine... as long as I don't press F5 too quickly.

In the end I added a wait of 1s after each Paste, and this way the code runs without any error till the end (but crazy slow for a few thousands paste).

Below the code I currently run:

```
Sub Change_to_icon()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C4:AI28")
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = "0"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("CD").Copy
        cell.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ElseIf cell.Value = "2" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("CDW").Copy
        cell.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ElseIf cell.Value = "3" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("E").Copy
        cell.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ElseIf cell.Value = "4" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("CT").Copy
        cell.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    End If


Next cell

End Sub
```

In some other topics someone was suggesting in some rather similar situation than there may be a discrepancy in the loop like trying to paste before copy (I fI understood well), and to add some DoEvents. I also tried this at different places in the code. Didn't change anything.

Also, all the new shapes pasted have similar names, I could imagine that it has some unexpected side effect somewhere but I didn't try to give them a new name for each Paste.

What do you think is happening when it's running full speed without the Wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Copy&Paste, you can use `Shape.Duplicate`. The following code took less than 2s to copy more than 1000 shapes on my computer:

```
With ActiveSheet

    Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In .Range("C4:AI28")

        Dim shapeName As String
        shapeName = ""

        Select Case cell.Value
            Case 0: cell.Value = 1
            Case 1: shapeName = "CD"
            Case 2: shapeName = "CDW"
            (...)
        End Select

        If shapeName <> "" Then
            Dim shCopy As Shape
            Set shCopy = .Shapes(shapeName).Duplicate
            shCopy.Left = cell.Left
            shCopy.Top = cell.Top
            shCopy.Name = shapeName & "_" & cell.Address(False, False)
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this inconvenient, looks like the clipboard gets stuck when it's trying to do the copy and paste, after playing a while a found something that helps me.

1. First, set a function to set a delay time

   ```
    If VBA7 Then    
         Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #Else

    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

    #End If

    Sub prcWaiting(ByVal Mili_Seconds&)
        Sleep Mili_Seconds
    End Sub
   ```
2. I create a function that will do specifically the copy, and set and error handler to know if the copy was made or not if was made go true otherwise with an error false

   ```
    Private Function funCopyMinusButton() As Boolean
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Sheets("_Resources").Shapes("btnMinus").Copy

        funCopyMinusButton = True
    Done:
        Exit Function

    ErrHandler:
        funCopyMinusButton = False
    End Function
   ```
3. Where the code of copy is required I put some sort of cycle if the function returns false I give 2 seconds to Excel to release the clipboard and then try again the copy, sometimes may be in the cycle for couple of seconds and then continues the copy-paste process

   ```
    errTry:

    If Not funCopyMinusButton Then
        prcWaiting 2000
        GoTo errTry
    End If
   ```

I hope this works for others with same error.